# C forking doesn't work

Tags: c, fork

I'm trying to make a server where it listens to 2 ports and does something with the incoming data, while printing out a dot every second to let people know it's still running. I want to do this by using `fork()`. I'm trying:

```
  p = fork();
  if(p == 0){
      if( getsockname( sock1, (struct sockaddr *) &name1, &length1) == -1 ) {
        perror( "getting socket name" );
        exit(3);
      }
      printf( "Socket port #%d\n", ntohs( name1.sin_port ) );

      if( getsockname( sock2, (struct sockaddr *) &name2, &length2) == -1 ) {
        perror( "getting socket name" );
        exit(3);
      }
      printf( "Socket port #%d\n", ntohs( name2.sin_port ) );

  }
  else if(p > 0){
      printf("inhere"); //
      p1 = fork();
          if(p1 > 0) {
            while(TRUE) {
               write(".");
               sleep(1);
            }
          }
...
```

This doesn't even print the `inhere` string in the child process. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (p==0) is a child process not (p>0).

Comment: Not having a linefeed at the end of `"inhere"`, thus trapping that in the standard library's outgoing line buffer is my first guess. No idea why there is another `fork()` call in there.

Comment: According to my manpage for `sleep`, the parameter is number of seconds to sleep.
`sleep(1000000000000000);` might sleep a bit longer than you intented.

Comment: It doesn't work for `sleep(1)` either.

Comment: `if (p == 0) { ... } else if (p == 0) { ... }` really??

Comment: @pmg not really, just made a bad edit to the post by mistake.

Comment: Does the compiler give you any warnings about the `write(".");` line?

Comment: No. I'm using write bc I read that to avoid the message being held up in the buffer, I should use write. Apparently that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child process gets a 0 as the return value.  You might call an fflush(0) right after the printf call and see if it helps.